# Have a line where one point is stationary and the other follows a moving object?

Tags: java, java-3d

I'm fairly new to Java3d, so excuse my ignorance. In my Java3d universe there are 2 objects: Some stationary text and a shape that's being rotated with a RotationInterloper.

My question is what is the best way to have a line going from the stationary text to the rotating shape *and* have the line follow the shape while it's rotating? I'm going to be drawing the line with code like this:

```
Point3f[] plaPts = new Point3f[2];
plaPts[0] = new Point3f(somex1, somey1, somez1);
plaPts[1] = new Point3f(somex2, somey2, somez2);
LineArray pla = new LineArray(2, LineArray.COORDINATES);
pla.setCoordinates(0, plaPts);
previousShape = new Shape3D(pla, genColorAppearance(Color.red));
previousShape.setCapability(Shape3D.ALLOW_APPEARANCE_WRITE);
```

The only way I can come up with is to keep adding and removing a line between the text and the shape. This issue though is a) I have no idea how to get shapes real current coordinates and b) it sounds horrendously slow. I just don't know what to do though

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're still interested in this question i could help you out, I'm asking because it seems this question has gone stale but if the information would help you id be happy to help

Comment: @John I'm still interested. This was part of a random side project that's been collecting dust, so it would be interesting to try it out again

Comment: Ok ill work on it tonight for you, just wanted to make sure my efforts weren't going to be wasted